# importing CvVideoCamera

Tags: ios, swift, opencv3.0

I'm newbie in OpenCV and i am having difficult time to use CvVideoCamera in my swift project!

i am using openCV 3.2.0 and swift 3.1

i've got OpenCVWrapper files and also i import it in my bridging header.
inside my OpenCVWrapper.mm file i import **opencv2/videoio/cap_ios.h** but still in my swift view controller i don't get any CvVideoCamera type !!

here are my wrapper and bridging header

OpenCVWrapper.h

```
#import <UIKit/UIKit.h>
#import <Foundation/Foundation.h>

@interface OpenCVWrapper: NSObject
@end
```

OpenCVWrapper.mm

```
#include <opencv2/opencv.hpp>
#include "OpenCVWrapper.h"
#import <opencv2/videoio/cap_ios.h>

using namespace cv;
using namespace std;

@implementation OpenCVWrapper : NSObject


@end
```

and CSOpenCV-Bridging-Header.h

```
#import "OpenCVWrapper.h"
```

can anyone tell me why i can not initiate CvVideoCamera in my swift view controller

p.s: i also try to import **opencv2/videoio/cap_ios.h** directly in my bridging header file but got compiler errors saying

> error base.hpp header must be compiled as C++

Answer (score 3, accepted):

okay after giving up on swift for using opencv i found an example application on github which used AVCaptureSession and AVCaptureVideoDataOutput to get camera feed, then used

```
func captureOutput(_ captureOutput: AVCaptureOutput!, didOutputSampleBuffer sampleBuffer: CMSampleBuffer!, from connection: AVCaptureConnection!)
```

to get sample buffers from session. then used a opencvwrapper to convert CMSampleBuffer to cv::Mat.

checkout [here](https://github.com/zzzel/RealtimeOCR/tree/master/OpenCVT) for sample codes.